# java regular expression to extract uuid within square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have string inside brackets like following format:

```
[space string space]
```

I want to extract the string if the string is in UUID format.

example : `[ d6a413f4-059c-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b ]`

With java regular expression how can I get `d6a413f4-059c-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b` ?

Comment: a simple String.substring would do, no reason to go all regex on it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen where did you find the 3rd arguments for String.replaceAll ???

Comment: `str.replaceAll("\\[\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\]", "$1")`

Answer (score 1):

For your given example, you could use a [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match what is between the `[` and the `]`:

[`(?<=\[ ).*?(?= \])`](https://regex101.com/r/4KjBFC/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?= \])` positive lookbehind to assert that what is before is `[`
- `.*?` match any character zero or more times non greedy
- `(?= \])` positive lookahead to assert that what follows is `]`

For example:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\[ ).*?(?= \\])";
String string = "[ d6a413f4-059c-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b ]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

[Java example output](http://rextester.com/TAY56170)

Comment: You should provide Java code as this question was tagged with Java.

Answer (score 0):

## Using regex

```
\[ ([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}) ]
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2LIAf3/1)

## Why you don't want to do this

If you know that your string will definitely have the right format then you can just use substring to get the UUID

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "[ d6a413f4-059c-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b ]";
        System.out.println(s.substring(2, s.length()-2));
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoIwFEVn@IoXJprYhiIqxPgJTozGoYWCRSiEV0iM4dtro5t3ucM993RiFXSclOnqZ@Fc1QtEuApt4B0G0yJ7XQFaYX2to65h8FNc2lmbljEGYm6ReBT@8iMA4QLRDeqjyPi@yWhyKCrKucqpFHlBE1UfmrxoTjyXcI/OYRCUL7RqYONi2eQVtjcxMlwkfoVxugNkvTKtfcSEpoT4zxZuzn0A)

This will be faster than using the regex option.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex to check if given String contains valid UUID:

```
"\\[ ([a-f0-9]{8}\\-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}\\-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}) \\]"
```

### So, what is going on in this regex:

`\\[`  - character ‘`[`‘ and whitespace after it

`[a-f0-9]{8}` – characters from ‘`a`’ to ‘`f`’ and from ‘0’ to ‘9’ exactly eight times (`123e5670` part)

`\\-` - ‘`-`‘ character

`(?:[a-f0-9]{4}\\-){3}` – non-capturing group that you want to be present exactly three times (this non-capturing group should contain exactly 4 characters that are in the range from ‘`a`’ to ‘`f`’ or from ‘`0`’ to ‘`9`’. After these 4 characters there must be present ‘`-`‘ character) (`a234-b234-c234-` part)

`[a-f0-9]{12}` - characters from ‘`a`’ to ‘`f`’ and from ‘`0`’ to ‘`9`’ exactly twelve times (`d23456789012` part)

`\\]` – whitespace and ‘`]`’ character
After searching String for match with `find()` method, you only print capturing group #1 with `group(1)` method ( capturing group #1 is contained in parenthesis `()` )

**Your UUID is in capture group 1**. Here is a simple example how you can get UUID from source String:

```
String source = "[ 123e5670-a234-b234-c234-d23456789012 ]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[ ([a-f0-9]{8}\\-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}\\-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}) \\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I couldn't explain my question properly. Using substring() I can get the string inside the brackets which I need to know if uuid or not. Not necessarily the string inside will always be a uuid.

Comment: @FahimQuadery You might want to have a look at my answer as I edited it. I hope now it meets your expectations :-)

Comment: @FahimQuadery Glad that I could help. If I can suggest something - I think that you should edit your question and contain information about that you need to make sure that checked String is a valid UUID, as now it is unclear that you want it. Just to avoid wrong answers like mine in the first attempt.